# Failed to edit crontab (linux Alpine)

Tags: cron, alpine-linux

I faced an issue with crontab in alpine under my non-root account.

```
bash-4.3$ crontab -e
crontab: must be suid to work properly
```

Here is the output of *id* command:

```
bash-4.3$ id
uid=41532(fred) gid=41532(fred) groups=41532(fred),41532(fred)
```

Btw everything works for root account.

Comment: This question would probably be a better fit for [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com).

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/bin/crontab` say?

Comment: it says
`lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Mar  2 16:20 /usr/bin/crontab -> /bin/busybox`

Comment: and `ls -la /bin/busybox` says
`-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        809128 Dec 16 08:00 /bin/busybox`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The solution is:

```
apk add --update busybox-suid
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation to your answer?

Comment: @GrantGryczan editing crontabs requires busybox-suid package, so you have to install it.