# How to set cronjob with non-root user?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, system

Error :   crontab: must be suid to work properly

I want to set cronjob in docker container with non-root user. Is it possible to set a cron without using sudo and without installing cron?
I am using alpine docker container.

Comment: Without sudo: yes, any user can use cron (if so configured).  Without installing cron: no.  cron is required to run cron (!).

Answer (score 19):

Yes you can run its own, cron in specific user without sudo, As each user will be having the crontab file no need to install it explicitly.
to run crontab of any user, use `-u` option , please note  that **user must be privileged to use -u**

```
 $ crontab -u <username> -e
```

Comment: crontab: must be suid to work properly
I am getting this error

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36714096/5113030 (*Failed to edit crontab (Linux Alpine)*...)

Answer (score 14):

`/etc/crontab` is the system wide `crontab`.

The format of `/etc/crontab` is like this:

```
# m h dom mon dow user      command
*   *  *   *   *  someuser  echo 'foo'
```

while `crontab -e` is per user, it's worth mentioning with no -u argument the crontab command goes to the current users crontab. You can do `crontab -e -u <username>` to edit a specific users `crontab`.

Notice in a per `user crontab` there is no `'user'` field.

```
# m h  dom mon dow  command
*   *   *   *   *   echo 'foo'
```

An aspect of crontabs that may be confusing is that root also has its own crontab. e.g. `crontab -e -u root` will not edit `/etc/crontab`

See Configuring cron for more information: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/configtuning-cron.html

In most Linux distros, per user crontabs are typically stored in: `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/<username>`

Comment: crontab: must be suid to work properly
I keep getting this error

Comment: But is there a way to make a cron file (non-interactively) without sudo for a particular user?

Answer (score 1):

**I solve it** adding the name of the user we need to execute cron jobs in the file /etc/cron.allow. If this files does not exists you have to create it. [More details about cron.allow file](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-restrict-at-cron-command-to-authorized-users/)